# ckeditor: Source-View Code is change with &nbsp; ( <br /><br /><br /> is replace to <br /<br />&nbsp; )

Tags: ckeditor

How can i protect my code?

CKEditor 4.4.7 change my code!

For example:

```
<br /><br /><br /><h1>Schritt 1</h1>
```

replace with:

```
<br />
<br />
&nbsp;
<h1>Schritt 1</h1>
```

I will protect my code, that ckeditor is not change any code. What can i do?

Comment: CKEditor practically always changes the code, it's not sane to try to make it not change the code. I suggest that you work with it. BUT; does it actually remove one `<br />` completely and converts it with the nbsp? Can you make this happen in the CKEditor demo on their website? Because if so, that's a bug. Also I suggest looking at the hex data to make sure everything is normal with that 3rd BR.

Comment: Its a bug. See here: http://downloads.psd-tutorials.de/ckeditor4/bug.gif

On the ckeditor demo page without config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;

replace my code:

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h1>Schritt 1</h1>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

Answer (score 0):

I replied to your ticket - http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12917#comment:4.

Quoting myself:

> Replacing the last 
>  before block end/start is a part of content normalization which CKEditor must do.

More details can be found in http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12879 where I also show that if the content was created by CKEditor it would not happen as well as that **both contents are visually identical**.

You can't expect that CKEditor will keep every detail of HTML that you load, because it's not an HTML editor. It's an editor for content represented in HTML. These are two different things.

Comment: I think it's a shame, however, if i have successfully operated over 7 years with the ckeditor2 / ckeditor3 and the update to version 4 change the code on edit. this is a bug in version 4 and not functional for me.

Comment: Reinmar: we actually use the ckeditor to edit fragments of html that iare assembled into a larger html document so this would actually affect it visually as you can see here:http://jsbin.com/qodiyanobi/1/edit?html,output